# Does HtmlAgilityPack implement the standard HTML5 parsing algorithm?

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

When I parse an HTML5 document such as:

```
<p>Content</p>
```

using HtmlAgilityPack with default options, it parses it successfully, but the constructed `HtmlDocument` does not include the `<html>` and `<body>` elements that the standard HTML5 parsing algorithm would construct.

Are there options I am missing that would do this?

Or is there some other library (.NET 6) that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that unless the functionality is very well hidden, HtmlAgilityPack does not offer this capability.

I discovered the package AngleSharp, which seems to meet my requirement.

Well, almost. Parsing `<p>Content</p>`, I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD/>
<BODY><P>Content</P></BODY></HTML>
```

I need to do a bit of further work to get the element names in lower case, but we're close.